# VMWare Player disrupting Samba on Ubuntu 9.04 host?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware, samba

I've had Ubuntu 9.04 running on this computer for a while now.  I just installed VMWare Player on my system and now when I try to browse the network in the Ubuntu host all the computers will show up one time only.  If I try to browse again, no computers appear and even the workgroup is missing.  I have to run:

`sudo /etc/init.d/vmware stop`
`sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart`

to get the network visable again.  As long as VMWare Player is stopped Samba seems fine.   I guess it's got to do with the virtual adaptors that VMWare installs.  Is there a way to get them both to work, or did I just miss-configure something?

Comment: Are you running an VMs at the time?

Comment: No, I only use VMWare occasionally.  There are no virtual machines running.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the other networks that exist when VMware is up and running. I suggest you samba to only bind to the interface you want it to, and not to the vmnet interefaces that VMware sets up. To do this, edit your samba configuration in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, and look for the lines that look like this:

```
# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
```

You should probably change the interfaces to just your physical adapter (find it with `ifconfig -a`):

```
# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
   interfaces = eth0
```

Don't forget to remove the semi-colon to uncomment the line.